# using google places api in xamarin forms ios platform

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, google-places-api

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for IoS and cant seem to find a package/tutorial for using google places api (can find only for android). Am i on the right path or is there any other path I should take (like Mapkits etc) thanks all

Comment: There is this plugin developed by Mr. Muhaym. I am using it in production and it works fine except for a crash on ipads :( https://github.com/muhaym/crossplacepicker#important-permission-and-setup-information

Comment: I was trying to learn how to bind native libraries using that example but forgot about it until now. I also handled the Ipad case using on-idiom and OnDevice conditions

Comment: it appears to me like even if using xamarin.forms, api calls should be native?? mapkits for ios and google for android? please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Xamarin will compile to native code. So, in a sense it will be a native call. But, if a developer can create a library and bind native code and api to C#. Then, you can use this plugin instead of writing the code using dependency service or other options. Xamarin should have full access to native SDK on each platform it supports

Comment: There are legal reasons for lack of tools. Google disallows results from several apis to be displayed on non google maps. Other apis are allowed to be displayed on google maps on iOS, but google wants money on iOS, which makes them not too successful. So carefully read googles legal stuff.

Comment: hey @GerdCastan, thanks for the input man. Would it be better for me to use Mapkits on IOS and GoogleMaps for android?? although im developing xamarin forms for shared code, wouldnt doing so defeat the purpose ?

Comment: I use MapKit on iOS (Swift) and will use Google Maps (Kotlin) when/if I support Android. While there are reasons to use Google on both platforms (Google has better data at the moment), I chose MapKit on iOS because it has a really nice UI and because of license/price reasons: Read Googles legal fine print what they allow and charge on other platforms. Since I don't know what I will earn with my app, I will not pay for googles routing when I get apples routing for free. (But be aware that you don't get public transport routing from Apple)